# Data type mismatch in criteria expression in the INSERT statement

Tags: vb.net

When running the program i get an error saying 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.' and the line `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` is highlighted. In my database the datatype for 'ID' is AutoNumber and the datatype for 'Calories Burned'  is decimal and everything else is text. I don't know if it is do with fact that when i input data into the text boxes its classed as a string. but if someone could help i would appreciate it a lot.

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    ' add data to table '
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        ' open connection '
        cnn.Open()
    End If

    cmd.Connection = cnn
    If Me.txtID.Tag & "" = "" Then


        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Training log] ([ID], [Runner Name], [Running Average Speed], [Cyclying Average Speed], [Swimming style] , [Calories Burned]) VALUES ('" & Me.txtID.Text & "' , '" & Me.txtRunnerName.Text & "' , '" & Me.txtRunSpeed.Text & "' , '" & Me.txtCycleSpeed.Text & "', '" & Me.txtSwimStyle.Text & "', '" & Me.txtCaloriesBurned.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Else
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Training log] SET ID=" & Me.txtID.Text & ", [Runner Name]='" & Me.txtRunnerName.Text & "', [Running Average Speed]='" & txtRunSpeed.Text & "', [Cyclyin Average Speed]='" & txtCycleSpeed.Text & "', [Swimming style]='" & txtSwimStyle.Text & "', [Calories Burned]='" & txtCaloriesBurned.Text & "' WHERE ID='" & txtRunnerName.Tag & "' "
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
```

Comment: SQL-Injection alert on your `txtID`-textbox for inputs like `');DROP Table [Training log]`. Use sql-parameters instead of string concatenation.

Comment: You might want to take a moment to learn about [Datatypes in VB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to remove the single quotes around your non-string values.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Training log] ([ID], [Runner Name], [Running Average Speed], [Cyclying Average Speed], [Swimming style] , [Calories Burned]) VALUES (" & Me.txtID.Text & " , '" & Me.txtRunnerName.Text & "' , '" & Me.txtRunSpeed.Text & "' , '" & Me.txtCycleSpeed.Text & "', '" & Me.txtSwimStyle.Text & "', " & Me.txtCaloriesBurned.Text & ")"
```